# How to get text from a custom ListView?

Tags: android

I'm developing a client server android app. When i press on the fab, in the dialog I can choose the pizzas I want. Then, when i press "ok" the pizzas I chose are shown in a custom listview when I can set the quantity and other notes for each type of pizza. I have another button "Invia" and I'd want that if it's pressed, data is taken from each item and is put in each object "ordine" of an array list of objects called "ordinazioni".

This is the method that it's called when I press the button "Invia". It should get the text from the listview and put it in the array of objects. I don't know how to test if it works but when I press the button, my app crashes. Please what am I doing wrong?

```
public void inviaOrdinazione(View view){
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);;
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Ordinazione ordinazione = new Ordinazione(listview.getCount());
    ordinazione.setnTavolo(Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));
    for(int i=0; i<listview.getCount(); i++){
        TextView tv = (TextView) listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textView);
        EditText et1 = (EditText) listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) listview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        ordinazione.ordinazione[i].setPizza(tv.getText().toString());
        ordinazione.ordinazione[i].setQuantità(Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()));
        ordinazione.ordinazione[i].setNote(et2.getText().toString());
    }
    /*try{
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(ordinazione);
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Errore: "+e);
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Errore: "+e);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Errore: "+e);
    }*/
}
```

This is the code of the class "Ordinazione" that creates the array of objects "Ordine"

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class Ordinazione implements Serializable{
private int nTavolo;
Ordine[] ordinazione;

public Ordinazione(int n) {
    ordinazione = new Ordine[n];
}

public Ordine[] getOrdinazione() {
    return ordinazione;
}

public void setOrdinazione(Ordine[] ordinazione) {
    this.ordinazione = ordinazione;
}

public int getnTavolo() {

    return nTavolo;
}

public void setnTavolo(int nTavolo) {
    this.nTavolo = nTavolo;
}
}
```

This is the code of the class "Ordine"

```
public class Ordine {
private String pizza;
private int quantità;
private String note;

public int getQuantità() {
    return quantità;
}

public void setQuantità(int quantità) {
    this.quantità = quantità;
}

public String getPizza() {

    return pizza;
}

public void setPizza(String pizza) {
    this.pizza = pizza;
}

public String getNote() {
    return note;
}

public void setNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
}
}
```

This is the layout of the custom adapter

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textPersonName|number"
    android:text="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Note"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me. I'm learning and I have to do this for school.

[image: Here is the image of the crash log]

This is the line 122 of MainActivity.java

```
ordinazione.setnTavolo(Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: post the crash log here and edit question

Comment: Done, please help @jagapathi

Comment: post MainActivity.java 122 line

Comment: Done @jagapathi

Comment: You called parseInt on an empty String...

Comment: You should not access the data from the Listview. Use the Java object data within the adapter

Comment: U cant change empty string to int check ur edittext

Comment: @cricket_007 can you explain me how to do that? What do you mean for "within the adapter"? Anyway when I press the button I have already written something in every edittext, so the string I get should not be empty. .

Comment: I have tried changing int variable into string variable, so I did't have to use parseInt, but I got the same problem :(

Comment: Listview  has a getAdapter method. All adapters have a getItem method